# PHP Get last increment of five minutes

Tags: php

I am looking to get the previous increment of five minutes from the current time...

Lets say that the current time is 12:07pm UTC

I want to put into a variable 12:05pm UTC

What would be an easy way of going about this?

Comment: You first need to convert the time to some form of time value and then extract the minutes.  You should then be able to manipulate the minutes.  Have a go and if you get stuck then add your attempt and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5)->format("h:i"), Using this you can easily get expected result.

Comment: @JasimJuwel, does that just subtract 5 minutes?  Also not sure if they are using Carbon, but if not it's a lot of extra code just to round to 5 minutes (IMHO)

Comment: @NigelRen yes it just subtracts 5 minutes

Comment: Whats up with the down vote?

Comment: If you read the down vote text - it says *This question does not show any research effort...*

Comment: oh, where can I find that at, whenever i get downvoted, im always like, what the hell...

Comment: @JeffreyL.Roberts put your cursor over the down arrow, then read the hover text; that is what downvotes mean ... if you are getting downvoted often that should be telling you something

Comment: People downvote for all sorts of reasons and unfortunately tend not to leave any hint as to why.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question gives some ideas.

Comment: @lagbox it happens from time to time, I wouldnt say often, usually when I dont know where to start

Comment: yea it will happen from time to time, you will need to explain that because often people will assume you didn't put in the effort to do the research otherwise ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in that allows you to retrieve 'increments' however you can calculate it with minimal code. The use of modulo here allows you to figure out how far past the most recent 5 minute mark is.  It will never be greater than 5 minutes (300 seconds) and can always be subtracted safely to take you back to the time you want.

```php
$now = time();
echo $now . PHP_EOL;
$five_minutes = 60*5; // 300
$offset = $now % $five_minutes;
$five_block = $now - $offset;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $five_block);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `DateTime` class (https://3v4l.org/7aqMH):

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('12:07 UTC');
$minutes = (int) $date->format('i');
$rounded = round($minutes / 5) * 5;

$date->setTime($date->format('H'), $rounded, $date->format('s'));
```

or more concisely:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('12:07 UTC');
$date->setTime(
    $date->format('H'), 
    round($date->format('i') / 5) * 5, 
    $date->format('s')
);
```

Comment: Haha, good spot! In my experiment I initially, mistakenly, applied the rounding to the seconds.

Answer (score 1):

First you will want to extract the minutes from their stored variable. Then mathematically this is simple by applying division and the floor function. To do this you can first divide by five using `intdiv(numerator, denominator)` which will remove any trailing decimal points and then multiply by five again to get your desired value at an increment of five.

Answer (score 1):

Get the current time using **time()** :

```
$min = 300
$currentTime = time();
$mod = $currentTime % $min;
$res = $currentTime - $mod;
finalResult =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $res);
```